# How to host 2 Django Application using gunicorn & nginx in Production

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, web-hosting

Hello I want to host 2 djagno websites using Gunicorn and Nginx and I don't know how to do this this is my first time to host 2 django websites in one server and 2 domain so please tell me how to host 2 django website.
Here is my 1 file located /var/www/site1
and here is my 2 file /var/www/site2

Comment: The solution is to configure a separate Gunicorn instance for each Django site (running each instance on a different port) and then use NGINX as a reverse-proxy to redirect specific URIs to each site. For instance you could point site1.example.com at the root of one site and site2.example.com at the other or use example.com/site1/ and example.com/site2/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you run your gunicorn instances on ports 8081 and 8082, you have two options:

## Option 1: Subdomains

To use subdomains to reverse-proxy with NGINX, see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/920534/nginx-proxy-subdomains-to-other-addresses-and-ports).

http://site1.example.com/ redirects to Site 1 and http://site2.example.com/ to Site 2.

NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    }
}
```

## Option 2: Locations

http://example.com/site1/ now redirects to Site 1 and http://example.com/site2/ to Site 2.

NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location /site1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
    location /site2/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    }
}
```

## EDIT - Option 3: Domains

You can also just use different domains for the different sites just as in option 1.

http://site1.com/ redirects to Site 1 and http://site2.com/ to Site 2.

NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    }
}
```

Note: These are bare minimum setups and may need additional configuration to work with your specific services.